# ЕГЭ, вопрос A29: обоснование суждения

Tags: егэ

Из Яндекс-ЕГЭ, [вариант 5, вопрос A 29](https://ege.yandex.ru/russian/question/A29/5/):

> (19) Может показаться странной и недостойной эта барахольная возня перед разлукой, скорее всего навечной, ничтожное копанье в шмотье посреди такой войны. (20) Неужели не было о чем поговорить, неужели не было друг для друга серьезных и высоких слов? (21) Все было, да не выговаривалось вслух. (22) Нас растили на жестком ветру и приучили не размазывать по столу масляную кашу слов.

Согласно ответам, выходит, что данное утверждение - не ошибочное:

> В предложении 22 представлено обоснование суждения, высказанного в предложениях 19,20.

Но мне кажется, что в предложении 22 обосновывается только суждение, высказанное в предложении 21. Если изъять предложение 21, то и обосновывать нечего, ИМХО:

> (19) Может показаться странной и недостойной эта барахольная возня перед разлукой, скорее всего навечной, ничтожное копанье в шмотье посреди такой войны. (20) Неужели не было о чем поговорить, неужели не было друг для друга серьезных и высоких слов? (22) Нас растили на жестком ветру и приучили не размазывать по столу масляную кашу слов.

Суждение исчезло вместе с предложением 21. Или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Суждение:** Хотя люди занимались мелочной возней и не говорили о высоких чувствах, им было  что сказать друг другу (три первых предложения).

**Обоснование суждения:** Но они не были приучены говорить о высоком.

Comment: Спасибо, Вера! Но проблема в том, что третье предложение (за номером 21) не указано: "В предложении 22 представлено обоснование суждения, высказанного в предложениях **19,20.**" Наверное, опечатка Яндекса, т.к. без него вроде бы и суждения нет.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, всё нормально.

(19) Может показаться странной и недостойной эта барахольная возня перед разлукой, скорее всего навечной, ничтожное копанье в шмотье посреди такой войны. (20) Неужели не было о чем поговорить, неужели не было друг для друга серьезных и высоких слов? - суждение о том,что кому-то может показаться странным, что вместо высоких слов на прощание Павлик отдаёт друзьям вещи на память.Предложение 20 воспроизводит вопрос от вымышленных собеседников, и уже интонация его говорит о несогласии автора с этим суждением(потом он подробно будет говорить об этом).

(22) Нас растили на жестком ветру и приучили не размазывать по столу масляную кашу слов.-это обоснование его несогласия с мыслями оппонентов.

Всё логично.

А в 4 варианте явная ошибка: там нет описания.